# Question on measure

Tags: measure-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Existence of a measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99130/existence-of-a-measure)

Let $(X,\mathfrak{B})$ be a measurable space. Could someone give me the steps to show that if $\mu$ and $\nu$ are measures on $\mathfrak{B}$ and $\mu\geqslant \nu$, then there exist a measure, say, $\alpha$ on $\mathfrak{B}$ such that $\mu = \nu +\alpha$.